# How to run a second ApplicationAdapter within one fluorinefx gateway

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, rtmp, fluorinefx

Im trying to have two ApplicationAdapters within one gateway. My instinct told me to look into config files:
remoting-config.xml and services-config.xml.

There are some channels defined, like:

```
<channel-definition id="rtmp-my-channel" class="mx.messaging.channels.RTMPChannel">
  <endpoint uri="rtmp://{server.name}:1935" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.RTMPEndpoint"/>
</channel-definition>
```

So I can add a channel here.

Also, I want to add another folder containing app.config to apps folder.

But then:

If a flash client connects to a given endpoint (say port 1935) how would it "know" which applicationAdapter should it access?

Hope i made myself clear:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I made it work.
There is no need to create a new  channel. All you have to do is:

create a folder in apps folder, which is going to contain a app.config file.

Every folder points an application adapter. So right now I have to folder in apps folder:

app1 and app2.

Both folders contain app.config file pointing to an application adapter. If your flash client wants to connect to the app1 it should connect to something like:

```
   rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/app1/?someParameters....
```

while if you want to get the connection to app2:

```
   rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/app2/?someParameters....
```

Maybe someone is going to need that..:)